# Can't use the Journal 3 theme

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I have the following set up on my server:

- PHP Version: 8.1.11
- Opencart: Version 3.0.3.9
- Journal 3: 3.2.0-rc.45

The setting above works great, all is running. But: when I want to activate Journal 3 under the OC admin panel "System / Settings / Edit Store / Theme -> Journal Theme" and want to save it, I get the following error message:

> **Warning: Please check the form carefully for errors!**

Anybody know how to solve this problem? Because the Journal support told me, that this problem is not Journal related, it has to be OC that occurs the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Journal theme on own risk. Journal theme is not supported by OpenCart.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, go to the last tab (server)
It probably says that there's an error with the max upload size as it defaults to 30000 or something.
I had the same issue after upgrading. The previous version had this value in bytes (30000 bytes) but now it expects MegaBytes so 30000MB is a bit much.

After changing it to 10 or whatever you like, it should work!

Answer (score 0):

The store admin is a part of default Opencart, not related to the Journal, they just link to it.

The error can be listed in another tab which is not currently active. There are some required fields that cannot be left empty.

So you just need to click on all other tabs to check if there are any errors highlighted in red there after you submitted the form. Most likely it's some missing value in the Store tab. Like email or telephone empty.

Answer (score -1):

you should fiell all fild in this page .check all field

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I noticed you're using the Beta version. Have you tried installing their new updated beta?

Journal v.3.2.0-rc.53